# jQuery when - wait for multiple success/done callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, .when

I´m using $.when to determine, when an array of ajax promises are finished. I encountered, that the moment $.when fires the ajax calls are finished, but their callbacks / done functions aren´t. How can I wait for the callbacks to be finished?

the ajax calls look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  }).then(
    function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      var url = data.url;

      obj.set('src', url);
  });
```

and $.when s.th. like this:

```
$.when(promises).done(function(){
    // the values of objs change in the .done function of the request above
    // but when the following ajax got fired, the values haven´t changed yet
    if(DEV) console.info('send Json: ', objs);
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: objs
    });
});
```

Comment: Assuming that `promises` is an array then your syntax is incorrect. Try `$.when.apply($, promises).done(...`

Comment: the `data = JSON.parse(data);` in your ajax function is not mutating the data object but create a new data object, you need to return it back so the caller can grab it

Comment: @AnthonyC you can't return anything from an async function

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes, you can, if the function that is in the then handler returns a value, the promise resolves/rejects with that value

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by using jQuery v1.8 or later and using `then` rather than `fail` and `done` and success/failure callbacks:

```
var promise1 = $.ajax({
    /* ...params...*/
}).then(
    function(data) {
        // Handle success; if you modify what you get, `return` it
        // and it will get propagated
        return /*...`data` or updated `data` as appropriate...*/;
    },
    function(error) {
        // Handle failure
    }
);
var promise2 = /*...*/;
```

Then

```
$.when(promise1, promise2).then(
    function(data) {
        // Handle overall success; this will be called after the
        // earlier `then` callbacks on each request
    },
    function(error) {
        // Handle failure
    }
);
```

[Live example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7yurt1s/2/) (sadly, Stack Snippets don't provide any ajax features); full source below

---

Note that `$.when` expects discrete arguments, not an array. If you really have an array, then:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(
    // ...
);
```

...or of course on a modern JavaScript engine:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(
    // ...
);
```

---

Full source of the fiddle above, which uses jQuery v2.2.4:

```
log("Starting");
var promise1 = $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json/"
}).then(
    function(data) {
        // Handle success; if you modify what you get, `return` it
        // and it will get propagated
        log("Got promise1's response, returning 'p1'");
        return 'p1';
    },
    function(error) {
        // Handle failure
    }
);
var promise2 = $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json/"
}).then(
    function(data) {
        // Handle success; if you modify what you get, `return` it
        // and it will get propagated
        log("Got promise2's response, returning 'p2'");
        return 'p2';
    },
    function(error) {
        // Handle failure
    }
);

$.when(promise1, promise2).then(
    function(result1, result2) {
        // Handle overall success; this will be called after the
        // earlier `then` callbacks on each request
        log("Both are done", result1, result2);
    },
    function(error) {
        // Handle failure
    }
);

function log() {
    // Old-fashioned to stay ES5 compatible
    $("<pre>").text(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ", ")).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Comment: $.when.apply($, promises) did the trick - I didn´t know that when can´t use arrays as param. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you chain your promises? With something like this (not tested):

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  }).then(
    function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      var url = data.url;

      obj.set('src', url);

      // return your promises (if possible, I don't know where they come from)
      return promises
  }).then(
    function() {
       if(DEV) 
         console.info('send Json: ', objs);
       $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: objs
       });
   });
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but this solution isn´t possible in my case - the first ajax-call is repeated multiple times simultaneously and I have to wait till every one of them is done.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: url,
data: formData,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
success: function(data){/* to handle success response */},
error: function(error){/* to handle error response */},
complete: function(data){/* to handle the response success or error*/}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

the `data = JSON.parse(data);` in your ajax function is not mutating the data object but create a new data object, you need to return it back so the caller can grab it 
Try it like this,

```
function getData(){
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
      }).then(
        function(data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          var url = data.url;

          obj.set('src', url);
          return data;
      });
}

var data = $.when(promises).done(getData);
```